# buscador con jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

en este caso quisiera crear mi propio input:search que me permita buscar en tiempo real datos de la tabla asi como lo hace el input:search que trae Jquery pero no puedo moverlo y colocarlo fuera de la datatable, quisiera saber si es posible o no, ya que en mi caso cuando autocargo la pagina el search y el show entries desaparecen y eso no me estaria convenciendo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que si creo un input que clases o que timpo de codigo necesitaria para que haga lo mismo que el input:search que hace jquery?

Comment: Ésta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/561252/mostrar-un-mensaje-cuando-no-filtre-ning%c3%ban-resultado-jquery) que hice te podría servir, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Es decir con ello estaria creando un buscador, mas no usando las librerias de Jquery(datatables) corrrecto?

Comment: El buscador es sin datatable, en tiempo real y en un input, es lo que buscas, ¿Cierto?...

Comment: en realidad la busqueda es justamente a la tabla, pero ya con ello me diste una idea y como acoplarlo gracias.

Comment: Con css siempre puedes moverlo

Comment: si claro, pero el problema no esta en la posición si no al momento de actualizar la pagina, el input desaparece y aparece al momento de finalizar la cargar los datos de la tabla.